# src folder not added to Java Classpath in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created a maven project and converted it into TESTNG.
Now I am trying to create a package under src folder.However no package is getting created rather only a normal folder is created.

It gives me the above error saying src folder not added to Java classpath.

Here is my .classpath file. how should I add src to it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/CDC-1.0%Foundation-1.0"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.8.0_73"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Source is not set in the BuildPath of your project.
Go into Project-> Properties->Java Build Path-> Source Tab-> select all the source folders(src)
Build it and you should be good.